# My Minecraft 1.13.1 single player world keeps crashing at the loading screen. What may be the cause and how can I fix it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Quite honestly, I wouldn't worry myself about that.

Time: 10/15/18 8:13 PM
Description: Exception in server tick loop

java.lang.RuntimeException: We are asking a region for a chunk out of bound | 27 26
    at ti.b(SourceFile:108)
    at axy.y(SourceFile:42)
    at ti.a(SourceFile:267)
    at byn.a(SourceFile:50)
    at byq.a(SourceFile:38)
    at tu.a(SourceFile:21)
    at tq.a(SourceFile:35)
    at bnc.a(SourceFile:95)
    at tx.a(SourceFile:79)
    at tx.a(SourceFile:25)
    at acu$a.a(SourceFile:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.13.1
    Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.11.3
    Java Version: 1.8.0_74, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 988566800 bytes (942 MB) / 1375731712 bytes (1312 MB) up to 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB)
    JVM Flags: 8 total; -Xss1M -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Player Count: 0 / 8; []
    Data Packs: vanilla
    Type: Integrated Server (map_client.txt)
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and both client + server brands are untouched.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really offer much help as to why, but I have used [Fenixin's Minecraft Region Fixer](https://github.com/Fenixin/Minecraft-Region-Fixer) to fix issues with corrupted region files for the worlds on my server.

The [usage page](https://github.com/Fenixin/Minecraft-Region-Fixer/wiki/Usage) has good instructions for how to use the program to scan/fix your files.